# "to be done" vs "to have done"

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

Could anyone please explain the differences between the following sentences and tell me whether they are correct or not.

> I want this job to be done within three days.
>
> I want this job to have done within three days.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence "*I want this job to be done within three days.*" means "**I want it to be finished withing three days**". You could also say, "**I want this job done within three days.**"

The second sentence "*I want this job to have done within three days.*" is incorrect and should instead be "**I want to have this job done within three days.**"